# Content Security Policy is blocking an svg icon sprite in Firefox

Tags: apache, svg, firefox, content-security-policy

I've tried searching the web, but had no luck. I've been using Chrome/Edge to work on my website and today I tried to open it in Firefox (93.0) and I noticed that none of my icons are loading. This error message appears in console:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
> resource at http://localhost/icons.svg (“default-src”).

This seems to indicate that the default-src was used as a fallback. I'm running an Apache server with this CSP:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; connect-src 'self'"
```

The icon sprite is used like this:

```
<svg class="icon"><use href="icons.svg#settings"></use></svg>
```

This is only an issue in Firefox since Edge, Chrome and iOS Safari all work fine. Is there any way for me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old Firefox browser bug - `img-src` directive does [not cover](https://csplite.com/csp/test414/) sources in the `<use xlink:href=>` tag.

Firefox uses `default-src` to control `<use xlink:href=>` tag, therefore to fix issue make `default-src 'self'` instead of `default-src 'none'`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I'm not very happy about this workaround, but I haven't found any other way to fix this.